# Android: is there any history of consumed IAP?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm treating IAPs as donations and consuming them immediately after purchase.

```
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        ...
            mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
        ...
}
```

Is there any way to identify if a user made a donation so I can unlock some extra functionality for him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my investigations, it seems that identifying consumed purchases is impossible.